# Marklogic Datahub: How to make a database invisible to a particular user accout

Tags: marklogic

I'm using Marklogic 10. I want to restrict the visibility of my databases.
How can I hide a database for a specific user? This user isn't an administrator but has access to qconsole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot restrict a Query Console user from seeing the list of databases in Query Console. You need to rely on document level permission to handle the ability to hide content(not the existence of a fatabase)

Separate from seing the databases, If your user can actually read, insert, update or see the URI content, then that is based on other permissions you have set yourself from another role. This is where URI permissions  are important - ensuring that someone cannot add arbitrary content (since document level permissions require a document to exist already)

In addition, your user maye be able to see the different app servers listed and set it as an execute context, but module execution permission is also not granted by default for your own modules databases, but added by your role assinment.

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution.

Instead of changing the permissions for each document in a database, is there any option to change the permissions for all the documents at once in a database?

Comment: You could always get all of the URIs of the documents and change permissions. On thousands, this sis fine for query console. Too many and it will time out, so you would want to paginate the process with other tooling.  It is a good idea to decide bk of document security upfront. Aaign a meaningful set of roles for your documents. Then changing which users have access to thise roles will drive whi can see them. Change role membership for users rather than all of the doc permissions. Further inquiries on new topics should be new questions. Keeps stack overflow clean and useful.